# Send email with confirmation link

Tags: php, email

I am making some sort of a Bulletin Board webapp. Users can add their listings to the bulletin board just like on craigslist for example. How do I implement the feature that when User wants to add a new listing to the site, he is sent an email where he has to click on a confirmation link, before the listing will be displayed on the site?
I guess I should mention that I'm working with PHP(codeIgniter framework).

Comment: Do you have some code, or are you asking for someone to write this for you?

Comment: I have no code for this specific task. This is more a question along the lines of where do I even start?. Does this kind of feature have a name, that I could search for and inform myself about?
 I do not want you to code it for me, but rather to give me some general hints.

Comment: You could start with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876139/how-to-generate-a-secure-activation-string-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but one good way to do that is sending the user an email with an encrypted querystring pointing to your php page, where you will get the
encrypted query and process all the parameters to add the listing to their bulletin board
.

Answer (score 0):

Your listing needs to have a status. When it is added the status can be Pending. When the user clicks on the link in the confirmation e-mail, the status is updated to something like Confirmed. Your listing page can then filter on Confirmed listings so that pending listings are ignored.