# Create an activation link for a website, what method to generate it?

Tags: php, encryption, registration, activation

I need to create an activation system for a website. The user registers, gets an email, then clicks a link with a secret key in the query string, and a script on my end decodes it.

My question is not on the programming itself, but rather, what is a good way of generating the link? Hashing was a thought but it is one way. Should I be encrypting something? Does anyone who has been tasked with this same thing have any insight?

Is there a way to do it that both:
Does not store any secret code in the database,
Does not put any obvious user info in the query string

The user is in a table with primary key id and other info. It does not need to be insanely secure but should not be easily breakable. I'm doing this with php. I couldn't find a similar question so if I have overlooked one I would appreciate a link.

Comment: check this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876139/how-to-generate-a-secure-activation-string-in-php

Comment: The safest way to do what you said is to use globally unique identifier (GUID, UUID, whatever the alias might be. In PHP there's a function called `uniqid()` that does something like that. MySQL on the other hand has a function called `UUID()`. Personally, I'd use MySQL's function to create `UUID()`, assign it to the record and then use that for sending out as an activation identifier. On the other hand, speed-wise, it's much more efficient to use PHP's `uniqid()` because it's shorter and indexing it will be more efficient.

Comment: Update: about NOT storing anything to the database - it's possible. You could encrypt the ID somehow, but then you risk possible breakage of your encryption method. Choosing one of AES algorithms and a good key might be sufficient. That way you won't store additional data (activation link) but you have a problem of how to safely send encrypted data. You could go with `base64_encode` to encrypt the ID. The other idea is to have additional column (or table mapping to records) and use globally unique identifiers that you send out via email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done this before by doing and md5 on the concatenated record id and email address. You could throw in a few extra characters or fields if you want. Then when the user clicks the link you just run the same select again to see if you get a match.

```
// generate the key
select md5(concat(id,email,'Some custom text')) as `verification_key` from ...

// verify the user
select * from user where '$verifikation_key' = md5(concat(id,email,'Some custom text'));
```

Then you can update the user record to mark as verified.

Comment: Thanks, our old system did not hit the table for activation so I was trying to avoid it, but this should work just fine for me.